# White bar appears when scrolling down despite fixed background HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ3P9.jpg)

When scrolling down this white bar appears and i have no idea why, because the background is fixed.
Also the bar seems to be in front of the background. I just startet with html, so i have little idea what the problem could be. Help would be greatly appreciated.
This is the Code:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://elearning.ohmportal.de/pluginfile.php/1/theme_boost_union/loginbackgroundimage/0/Wallpaper_Desktop_Jubila%CC%88um1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.fluid-container {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  padding: 48px;
  float:left;
  clear:both;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin:0px 0px 32px;
}
#left_colum_style {
  Width:554px;
}


.stylelogin{margin-block-end: 16px; border-radius: 25px;}
.inputpadding{ padding:8px 16px;border-radius: 5px; }
#login_button{background-color: #c72426; color:white; margin-block-end: 16px; border-radius: 5px; }

.login-divider {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <section id="left_colum_style" class="fluid-container">

        <div class="stylelogin">
            <img src="https://elearning.ohmportal.de/pluginfile.php/1/theme_boost_union/logo/1/1697685389/Ohm_Wort-Bild-Marke_RGB_Schutzzone.svg" class="img-fluid" alt="E-Learning TH Nürnberg">
        </div>
        
        <div class="stylelogin">
            <input type="text" name="username" class="inputpadding" value="" placeholder="Anmeldename" autocomplete="username">
        </div>
    
        <div class="stylelogin">
            <input type="password" name="password" value="" class="inputpadding" placeholder="Kennwort" autocomplete="current-password">
        </div>
    
        <div class="stylelogin">
            <button id="login_button" type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>

        <div class="login-divider"></div>

        <div class="stylelogin" style="text-align: left;">
            <h2>Kennwort vergessen?<br></h2>
            <a href="https://intern.ohmportal.de/index.php?id=3310">Angehörige der Technischen Hochschule Nürnberg Georg Simon Ohm</a><br>
            <a href="https://elearning.ohmportal.de/login/forgot_password.php">Alle anderen</a>
        </div>

        <div class="login-divider"></div>

        <div class="stylelogin" style="text-align: left">
            <h2> Information zur Anmeldung</h2>
            <ul><li>als Studierender der Technischen Hochschule Nürnberg Georg Simon Ohm, benutzen Sie bitte Ihre <strong>my.ohm </strong>Anmeldedaten,</li><li>als Nutzer von VHB-Kursräumen, benutzen Sie bitte die <strong>Weiterleitung </strong>über das VHB-Portal.</li></ul><p>Bitte nehmen Sie sich einen Moment Zeit und lesen Sie unsere <a href="https://www.th-nuernberg.de/index.php?id=6995" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">Nutzungsbedingungen</a>.</p> 
        </div>

    
    </section>  

</main>
```

i tried to rescale the body, but that did not work. other than that i have really no idea what the problem could be.

Comment: Your snippet here does not appear to reproduce the issue; neither in Chrome nor Firefox can I see the problem, no matter what viewport resolution I emulate.